# Value of b for which Tr(ABC)<-18

Tags: matrices

[image]

After multiplying I am getting

5xb+1<-18

after that I am confused how to proceed

Comment: Please take the time to type in important parts of your question instead of including them as images. Images aren’t searchable and are inaccessible to people using screen readers. If you aren’t willing to spend a bit of your own time to do this, why do you expect others to spend their time to help you with your questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake somewhere in your calculation. I calculated $$Tr(ABC) = -x^2+5bx-43$$
so for this to be less or equal to $-18$ is equivalent to $$x^2-5bx+25\ge 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$}$$ 
Hence $$\triangle = 25b^2-100\leq 0\implies b\in[-2,2]$$

Note: the matrix multiplication $AB$ gives $$AB = \left[
 \begin{matrix}
  -8  \\
  -3+bx  \\
  -4-x^2 
 \end{matrix} \right]
$$
Then, multiplying by $C$ gives $$ABC=\left[\begin{matrix}
  -24 &. &.  \\
  .  &-15+5bx &.\\
  . &. &-4-x^2
 \end{matrix} \right]$$
where I omitted the other terms because our goal is the trace, which is the sum of the three terms above: $Tr(ABC)=-x^2+5bx-43$.

Comment: If possible could you plese explain how you got Tr(ABC) . I am still getting wrong

Comment: I added it to the "Note:" section above.

Comment: I'm glad to help!